# OpenSSL Non-Blocking Socket SSL_read() unpredictable

Tags: c, sockets, openssl

I'm trying to make a non-blocking socket w/OpenSSL so I can loop over SSL_read() until there's no more data left, then break the loop. After a lot of work, I finally got the connection working, but now for the first thousand+ iterations SSL_read() will return -1. After, it will give me the actual data on the socket. SSL_read() also is not returning an accurate number of bytes read, it ALWAYS says -1 even when it's reading the correct bytes. I was able to get it working perfectly w/blocking sockets but non blocking seems problematic...

```
char *sslRead (connection *c)
{
const int readSize = 1024;
char *rc = NULL;
int r;
int received = -1, count = 0;
int TotalReceived = 0, ReallocSize = 0;
char buffer[1024];

if (c)
{
    while (1)
    {

        received = SSL_read (c->sslHandle, buffer, readSize);

    buffer[received] = '\0';

        TotalReceived += received;
        printf("Buffsize - %i - %s \n", received, buffer);


        if (received <= 0)
        {

            // this line added per advice of Eric Tsui but does not
            // change behaviour 
            received = SSL_read (c->sslHandle, buffer, readSize);



            //printf(" received equal to or less than 0\n")
            switch (SSL_get_error(c->sslHandle, received))
            {
                case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
                {
                        printf("SSL_ERROR_NONE %i\n", count);
                        //if (received != -1)
                        //  goto END;
                        break;
                }   
                case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN: 
                {
                        printf("SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN %i\n", count);
                        goto END;
                        break;
                }   
                case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ: 
                {
                        printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ %i\n", count);

                        break;
                }
                case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE: 
                {
                        printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE %i\n", count);
                        goto END;
                        //break;
                }
                default:
                {
                        printf("error %i\n", received); 
                        break;
                }
            }     


            count++;
        }
    }
}
END:
return rc;
}
```

If you've done this before, I'd really appreciate if you could tell me what's wrong with this code. Thanks.

Comment: If you're just going to read in a loop, why do you need it to be non-blocking? Do you have anything better to do instead?

Comment: Because if not the SSL_read() will block (I have no end of line character to search for) and program execution stops. It needs to be non blocking...

Comment: you must do `if (received <= 0)` check immediately after `received = SSL_read (c->sslHandle, buffer, readSize);`

Comment: Thanks for the help Eric, but I did that and it's still looping infinitely. How can I know the last byte has been read?

Comment: If `SSL_read()` returns `<= 0`, DO NOT call `SSL_read()` a second time.  Call `SSL_get_error()` immediately, and then loop back to the `SSL_read()` at the top of the loop **only if** the error is not fatal (`SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`, `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`, etc).

Comment: Thanks Remy, but that's what I was doing initially and it didn't work. Are you able to tell me whats wrong with the code... ? Is there any special way the socket needs to be initialized? The socket was initialized using fcntl() for non blocking and after connect() I set the timeout to 5 seconds w/select()...

Comment: I'd like to add that the program above has a buffer overflow. Also, I feel this question is a X Y problem - the real problem is "how do I read a variable-length record", because non-blocking mode will not help, as SSL_read can return more data than expected. The correct solution would be to read single bytes until the record is complete.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your loop is calling `SSL_read()` too many times, and your error handling is not breaking the loop when there really is no more data to read (the `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` condition).  Try something more like this instead:

```
char *sslRead (connection *c)
{
    const int readSize = 1024;
    char *rc = NULL;
    int received, count = 0;
    int TotalReceived = 0;
    fd_set fds;
    struct timeval timeout;
    char buffer[1024];

    if (c)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            received = SSL_read (c->sslHandle, buffer, readSize);
            if (received > 0)
            {
                TotalReceived += received;
                printf("Buffsize - %i - %.*s \n", received, received, buffer);
            }
            else
            {
                count++;

                //printf(" received equal to or less than 0\n")
                int err = SSL_get_error(c->sslHandle, received);
                switch (err)
                {
                    case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
                    {
                        // no real error, just try again...
                        printf("SSL_ERROR_NONE %i\n", count);
                        continue;
                    }   

                    case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN: 
                    {
                        // peer disconnected...
                        printf("SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN %i\n", count);
                        break;
                    }   

                    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ: 
                    {
                        // no data available right now, wait a few seconds in case new data arrives...
                        printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ %i\n", count);

                        int sock = SSL_get_rfd(c->sslHandle);
                        FD_ZERO(&fds);
                        FD_SET(sock, &fds);

                        timeout.tv_sec = 5;
                        timeou.tv_nsec = 0;

                        err = select(sock+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
                        if (err > 0)
                            continue; // more data to read...

                        if (err == 0) {
                            // timeout...
                        } else {
                            // error...
                        }

                        break;
                    }

                    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE: 
                    {
                        // socket not writable right now, wait a few seconds and try again...
                        printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE %i\n", count);

                        int sock = SSL_get_wfd(c->sslHandle);
                        FD_ZERO(&fds);
                        FD_SET(sock, &fds);

                        timeout.tv_sec = 5;
                        timeou.tv_nsec = 0;

                        err = select(sock+1, NULL, &fds, NULL, &timeout);
                        if (err > 0)
                            continue; // can write more data now...

                        if (err == 0) {
                            // timeout...
                        } else {
                            // error...
                        }

                        break;
                    }

                    default:
                    {
                        printf("error %i:%i\n", received, err); 
                        break;
                    }
                }     

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, this is correct! And thanks again for talking to me in code instead of a bunch of English, I appreciate that.

Comment: Hi Remy, after testing a while it works but there's a problem - this is going to wait 5 seconds even if data is available before that. So to send/receive data twice will take 20 seconds, when on a fast server it should take 1 - 2. Is there any way to make it read IF data is available, and make it wait ONLY if NO data is available? I'd like to keep the 5 second timeout because some servers need it, but most don't. I'd just like it so that it only waits that amount of time if necessary and not by default. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously, you would have to tweak the `select()` timeout to suit your needs. But you do have to take network lag into account. Without a distinct delimiter between messages, timeouts are all you have to work with. What I gave you already does what you are asking for. As long as data is available, it does not need to wait. It only waits when data is not available. But what exactly is being sent that does not delimit its messages in *some* manner?

Comment: From the man page: "SSL_pending(3) can be used to find out whether there are buffered bytes available for immediate retrieval."